# Obtaining zero or one record instead of a list of records

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

Using Spring JDBC I find myself doing stuff like this all the time:

```
NamedParameterJdbcTemplat njt = ...;

String SQL = "SELECT blah FROM blah_table WHERE column = :condition";
SqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource('condition', variableName);
List<Integer> rows = njt.query(SQL, params, Integer.class);

if(rows.size() == 0)
{
    //record did not exist, whew avoided index out of bounds exception
}

//do something with rows.get(0);
```

There has to be a better way right?

Comment: What's special about the first row of your result set? Are you typically expecting only one or zero rows, not multiple rows?

Comment: Can you not use the `List'`s iterator?

Comment: @GriffeyDog Yes, exactly. Sorry I did not clarify that.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: @thatidiotguy I probably didn't either. Are you trying to find a better way to write `if (rows.isEmpty())) {...} else {...}`?

Comment: You can use `queryForObject` instead, if you are expecting zero or one row.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `queryForObject`, e.g.:

```
Integer i = null;
try {
    i = template.queryForObject(sql, Integer.class, args);
} catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) { // zero rows
}
```

You could write your own wrapper method to deal with the EmptyResultDataAccessException and make it cleaner.

Comment: I was aware of this syntax but it seems weird to have to rely on an exception to handle this case. If there is no better option I will accept your answer. I have been doing it in the way I illustrated because it felt better than relying on an exception, but in the end it is definitely not very different.